# how to abort multiple ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

By clicking the show data button, my AJAX call is firing again and again the and same data gets added in to the table. Firstly, I want to stop that and secondly is there any way to update the database only with new data if some new data is added inside the database?

```js
var showdata = document.getElementById("showdata");
var btn = document.getElementById("getdata");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo base_url() ?>Appconfig/get_masteradmin_data", false);
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    renderHTML(ourData);
  };
  xhttp.send();
});

function renderHTML(data) {
  var html = '';
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    html += '<tr>' +
      '<td>' + data[i].full_name + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + data[i].username + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + data[i].designation + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + data[i].department + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + data[i].official_mobile_no + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + data[i].official_email_id + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + data[i].select_user_type + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + data[i].permission + '</td>' +
      '</tr>';
  }
  showdata.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use jquery html() method instead of showdata.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);